# PowerBI Automated Refresh using Enterprise Gateway

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am trying to automate a PowerBI report that uses excel documents as a source and I currently have access to the files. Problem now is that the Enterprise Gateway requires a username and password and mine don't work since I have windows authentication. Another problem is that the Gateway doesnt allow me to use Window Authentication for this particular source. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. I used my entire email address as my username and it solved the problem.